Attendance Sheet That Saves Records in a Database
Our company runs employee training classes almost every week. I am working on building out a Google Sheet we can use to track attendance for these classes.
The data entry page of this sheet is dynamic in that when the date at the top of the page is changed the list of employees attending training changes. What I am trying to accomplish is to have the attendance record copied to a separate page in my workbook where it will be stored.
I have the coding for copying the data from the first name on the list to the database page worked out. The piece I am struggling with is the coding for a loop that will move to the next record on the list and do the same thing for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc.
I am trying to create a loop inside of a loop - the outer loop would move down the attendance list (var a) - the inner loop is to copy to the data to the datasheet (var i).
To clarify the form section is a simple list of the names of the people attending the class with check boxes to mark them present.  The datasheet has a list of all of our employees. Once attendance has been taken I need to be able to push a "submit" button and have the function put the True/False response from the attendance form into the datasheet in the same row as the name.
This is a sample version of what I am trying to create: Master OBC Dashboard
function takeAttendance() {
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Set 
variable for Google Sheet
var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Attendance"); //Set 
variable for Attendance Form
var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Emp Data"); // Set 
variable for database
var classSize   = shUserForm.getRange("C4").getValue();  // Set 
variable for class size
let classRange  = shUserForm.getSheetValues(6,3,classSize,5); // 
Set range for class attendance data

for (var a = 6; a <= classRange.length+5; a++) //formula to 
advance through class roster
{
var Emp      = shUserForm.getRange(a,3).getValue(); //Set variable 
for Emp roster 
var values    = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //getting the entire values from Emp Data range and assigning it to values variable

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) // formula to search Emp Data for Emp Name in first column

 {
   var rowValue = values[i]; // declaring the data row as a variable

   //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
    if (rowValue[0] == ppAD) {

     var  iRow = i+1; //identify the row number
     console.log(iRow)

     datasheet.getRange(iRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange(a,3).getValue());     //ppAD Name
     datasheet.getRange(iRow, 22).setValue(shUserForm.getRange(a,4).getValue());    //Day 1
     datasheet.getRange(iRow, 23).setValue(shUserForm.getRange(a,5).getValue());    //Day 2
     datasheet.getRange(iRow, 24).setValue(shUserForm.getRange(a,6).getValue());    //Day 3
     datasheet.getRange(iRow, 25).setValue(shUserForm.getRange(a,7).getValue());    //Day 4

   valuesFound=true;
  return; //come out from the search function

  }

return;}

}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike - Thank you for reviewing my question. I just edited it to try to clarify how I need the sheet to function - let me know if you need any further clarification

I had to guess at some of this because there wasn't enough info in your question to figure out exactly what the designation range is.
function takeAttendance() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ash = ss.getSheetByName("Attendance");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Emp Data");
  const classSize = ash.getRange("C4").getValue();
  let classRange = ash.getSheetValues(6, 3, classSize, 5);
  let vs = classRange.getValues();
  let data = vs.reduce((acc,[a,b,c,d,e],i) => {
    acc.col1.push([a]);
    acc.col22.push([b,c,d,e])
    return acc;
  },{col1:[],col22:[]})
  const sr = 1;//wherever you wish to start putting data in
  dsh.getRange(sr,1,data.col1.length).setValues(col1);
  dsh.getRange(sr,22,data.col22.length,4).setValues(col22);
}

I don't follow links to google accounts.
